# SQL Server Management Studio 17.6 crash at start: SSMS has stopped working

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Please, this is driving me crazy.

SSMS was working fine. But yesterday I tried to open it and it now shows a message that reads

> SSMS has stopped working, a problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available

I have googled around some solutions without avail, including uninstalling RedGate software, checking the integrity of .NET Framework installation, running as administrator and even removing and installing SSMS again. Nothing works. It just wont run.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what happens when you reinstall it? Same error? What's changed on your system? Do you have a recent restore point? It's unlikely we'll be able to figure out the problem--especially if reinstalling doesn't fix it.

Comment: @scsimon I will try to go for a restore point. Nothing seems to be working for SSMS 17.0 and up.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at windows event log and see if you find any additional information about the failure/crash and then proceed from there.

In Event Viewer,  application log and system log contains errors, warnings and information about applications running on your system.

Looking at them may give your additional information about the crash.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens in both SSMS 17 and 18, so I am listing both answers to help both.

Step1:

```
//For SSMS 17
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Interop.pkgdef

//For SSMS 18
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Interop.pkgdef
```

Rename `.pkgdef` extension to something else. Or remove the file.

Step2:

Delete Registry Key (created at SSMS 18 or SSMS17 at Startup using the `.pkgdef` file mentioned above):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0_IsoShell_Config\RuntimeConfiguration\dependentAssembly\bindingRedirection\{8BC7AF31-B6DA-4B97-8B36-F0500DECB147}
```

Answer (score -1):

17.6 is only in preview at the moment. Stick with 17.5 until it's released

Comment: Downgraded, same problem.